HDD drive showing wrong mount folder and size
I have an old HP windows installed laptop and tring to install ubuntu using live Ubuntu and encountered a mount error on /efi/boot. I tried to fix it using gdisk, but that corrupted the HDD partition.
Before gdisk operation HDD had 3 partitions as sda4 300GB (label=arpita-drive), sda5 300GB (label=ashutosh-drive), 280 free space, and after gdisk operation it is showing a single partition of sda4 of 880GB with label =arpita-drive and I can see only the contents of arpita-drive.
In nautilus file explorer it is still showing 300GB for arpita-drive, but it is not showing any other drive partition.
How can I get back the ashutosh-drive partition and its contents?


---------------------------------------------
output of #lsblk -f
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsblk -f
NAME FSTYPE FSVER LABEL                 UUID                                FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
loop0
    squash 4.0                                                                      0   100% /rofs
loop1
    squash 4.0                                                                               
loop2
    squash 4.0                                                                               
loop3
    squash 4.0                                                                      0   100% /snap/core22/1564
loop4
    squash 4.0                                                                      0   100% /snap/bare/5
loop5
    squash 4.0                                                                      0   100% /snap/firefox/4793
loop6
    squash 4.0                                                                      0   100% /snap/firmware-updater/127
loop7
    squash 4.0                                                                      0   100% /snap/gnome-42-2204/176
loop8
    squash 4.0                                                                      0   100% /snap/snap-store/1173
loop9
    squash 4.0                                                                      0   100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop10
    squash 4.0                                                                      0   100% /snap/snapd/21759
loop11
    squash 4.0                                                                      0   100% /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/178
loop12
    squash 4.0                                                                      0   100% /snap/thunderbird/507
loop13
    squash 4.0                                                                      0   100% /snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237
sda                                                                                          
├─sda1
│   ext4   1.0                          3888ff7c-842d-469a-a8e8-a478ff417f3d             
├─sda2
│   vfat   FAT32                        4983-F83C                                        
├─sda3
│   swap   1                            64d4f374-5740-4aef-ac42-cedf7ebb890a                [SWAP]
└─sda4
    vfat   FAT32 Arpita Driv            C14D-55B4                                        
sdb  iso966 Jolie Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS amd64 2024-08-27-16-23-26-00                            
├─sdb1
│   iso966 Jolie Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS amd64 2024-08-27-16-23-26-00                    0   100% /cdrom
├─sdb2
│   vfat   FAT12 ESP                    3C53-CAEB                                        
├─sdb3
│                                                                                            
└─sdb4
    vfat   FAT32 piyush                 1C2E-AE04                                        
sr0             


Better to just post output to lsblk -f to show partitions. Was drive MBR(msdos) before. Normally conversion from MBR to gpt totally erases drive. And gdisk my convert, but still requires you to have good backups. If very old system that was BIOS/MBR, you may need lighter weight flavor as Ubuntu is more for newer systems. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie
Flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors)
I use Kubuntu, more of a mid-weight.

@oldfred I added the output of lsblk -f, after the gdisk run sda5 disappears and sda4 showing combined partiotion size.

Please post terminal output directly not as screen shot. It just looks like you overwrote all your old partitions. Best to start over & restore from backups.

@oldfred I am sharing the command output using gdrive (https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rWtt47gApxxDDM43c35HGnhInpchOCVk3BJS4r15uRM/edit?usp=sharing) as there is character limit in comment section. This disaster happened while taking backup of this old laptop. I do not have backup of the data. I never do any operation or formatting on sda4.

I did below commands run :
gdisk /dev/sda
Creating new GPT entries in memory.
Command (? for help): t
Partition number (1-128, default 1): 1
First sector (34-234441614, default = 2048) or    {+-}size{KMGTP}: 40
Last sector (2048-234441614, default = 234441614) or {+-}size{KMGTP}: 200M
Current type is 8300 (Linux filesystem)
Hex code or GUID (L to show codes, Enter = 8300): ef00
Changed type of partition to 'EFI system partition'

Do not post in comments as it loses formatting and then is very difficult to read. Post in question. Cannot tell sda or sdb is drive you are concerned about. On my system when I plug in a flash drive it becomes sda on reboot, but is sdb when plugged in. So I have to pay close attention to drive order. Exactly what commands did you do for backup and with what program/commands. I prefer rsync, but to multiple places.
